# Pandas and Google Analytics

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-analytics, google-api, pandas

I have been using Pandas for accessing and analysing my Google analytics data for several months however yesterday my code failed and I'm not sure why. Even using the most basic example (as given in the documentation) the **ga.read_ga** function is returning an error:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ipython-0.13.1-py2.7.egg/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    176             else:
    177                 filename = fname
--> 178             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/danielcollins/Documents/GA Python/EngCompCombined.py in <module>()
    161 #                  account_id=account_id,
    162                  max_results=max_results,
--> 163                  chunksize=5000)
    164 
    165 df1_conc = pd.concat([x for x in df1])

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/ga.py in read_ga(metrics, dimensions, start_date, **kwargs)
    100     reader = GAnalytics(**reader_kwds)
    101     return reader.get_data(metrics=metrics, start_date=start_date,
--> 102                            dimensions=dimensions, **kwargs)
    103 
    104 

/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/ga.py in get_data(self, metrics, start_date, end_date, dimensions, segment, filters, start_index, max_results, index_col, parse_dates, keep_date_col, date_parser, na_values, converters, sort, dayfirst, account_name, account_id, property_name, property_id, profile_name, profile_id, chunksize)
    254 
    255         account = self.get_account(account_name, account_id)
--> 256         web_property = self.get_web_property(account.get('id'), property_name,
    257                                              property_id)
    258         profile = self.get_profile(account.get('id'), web_property.get('id'),

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The format of the request is:

```
df1 = ga.read_ga(metrics,
                 dimensions = dimensions,
                 start_date = start_date, 
                 end_date = end_date, 
                 token_file_name = '-------',
                 filters = filters,
                 max_results=max_results,        
                 chunksize=5000)
```

I have never had to specify my account-id, profile-id etc but i have tried hardcoding them without much luck. This script was collecting data everyday until yesterday and I have not touched either my python script or my GA account config.

I am running Pandas 0.11.0 however I have tried reverting to 0.10.1 to see if the error remains.

Authentication flow via refresh token seems to work fine.

I really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Is this your [github issue](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/3908)? (or are multiple people having the same problem?)

Comment: Hi, Yes it's the issue i put on github. I was not sure if that was the best place to put it as the problem might lie elsewhere (especially if i'm the only one!)

Comment: I've just posted an update on the pandas github issue. I have a workaround which involves me hardcoding the values for account, web_property, profile and profile_id. I had tried some of these but not all (+ hadn't correctly bypassed the ga.py 'get' statements). I guess it was/is only a problem relating to my GA account.

Comment: Good work on the follow up, someone who knows about the ga bit have a look at it. That sounds a little hacky... :)

Comment: Agreed! On a related note, I want to thank you for all of your posts/answers regarding Pandas. Really helped me as I only started using it (and Python) a few months ago.

Comment: Glad I could help, keep up with the pandas! :)